# kernel 3.18.24 crashes on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: kernel, 15.10

Hi we are facing kernel crashes after 4-5 days.
We are using 3.18.24 kernel because of lacking drivers on BlackMagic devices (which are not ready for 4.2.0) - we suspected if the problem isnt coming from this driver which is not opensource.

We are using also AMD external graphics card with OSS radeon driver.
First crash was something about network card 8192 - I think some DNS

I can provide only image of backtrace of kernel panic(in logs there is nothing):
First crash:
[image: kernel panic1]

Second crash:

[image: kernel panic2]

I hope someone can help with narrowing down what could be the problem - if its possible on given informations.

Could it be HW problem?
Could it be some faulty driver?
Why is it always exception in interrupt?
Could it be some problem in OS-CPU communication(we use intel i7)?

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12557  0
btrfs                 933945  0
xor                    21411  1 btrfs
raid6_pq               97812  1 btrfs
ufs                    74682  0
qnx4                   13315  0
hfsplus               102898  0
hfs                    54678  0
minix                  36140  0
ntfs                  101408  0
msdos                  17332  0
jfs                   185313  0
xfs                   927132  0
libcrc32c              12644  1 xfs
intel_rapl             18783  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0
intel_powerclamp       18786  0
eeepc_wmi              13151  0
coretemp               13441  0
asus_wmi               24131  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
kvm                   470678  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    84373  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    68949  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     51974  1
snd_hda_intel          30520  5
snd_hda_controller     31093  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139458  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0
crc32_pclmul           13133  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
aesni_intel           169590  0
snd_pcm               105384  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
blackmagic            582869  0
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
mei_me                 19662  0
lrw                    13287  1 aesni_intel
shpchp                 37040  0
mei                    87928  1 mei_me
serio_raw              13434  0
soc_button_array       12722  0
lpc_ich                21093  0
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13944  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi           13564  0
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                67224  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29513  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    87611  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20360  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
8250_fintek            12925  0
mac_hid                13227  0
soundcore              15052  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
parport_pc             32741  0
ppdev                  17671  0
lp                     17759  0
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                38830  2
hid_generic            12559  0
usbhid                 52607  0
hid                   110155  2 hid_generic,usbhid
radeon               1570544  3
i2c_algo_bit           13406  1 radeon
ttm                    97523  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         98487  1 radeon
psmouse               111660  0
drm                   317482  6 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
ahci                   34099  2
r8169                  80568  0
libahci                32190  1 ahci
mii                    13934  1 r8169
wmi                    19193  1 asus_wmi
video                  20256  1 asus_wmi
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8576
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
03:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Blackmagic Design Intensity Pro
    Subsystem: Blackmagic Design Intensity Pro
    Kernel driver in use: blackmagic_driver
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8554
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
05:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850 / R7 265 / R9 270 1024SP]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 3011
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
07:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device aab0
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Ubuntu 15.10 64bit

Kernel 3.18.24-031824-generic installed from [Ubuntu kernel server](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18.24-vivid/)

Comment: Working Blackmagic drivers for 4.2 kernels:
https://github.com/iperry/blackmagic
https://github.com/iperry/blackmagic-io

Comment: thanks a lot @BrianTheLion you can add this as answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/704223/how-to-install-blackmagic-driver-for-4-2-0-linux-kernel

Answer (score 1):

Install AMD video driver by running

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and reboot.

Comment: thanks for quick answer. can you add explanation? do you have any bad experiences with radeon driver?  we would prefer to stick to opensource driver rather than proprietary.

Comment: YOU have a bad experience with `radeon` driver. It never worked well for new cards. If you prefer to have these crashes, it is your choice.

Comment: ok so the combination of radeon OSS driver and new card is not good.. I will test it and report later - but it takes usually a week to be sure that the crash didnt occured.. thanks for now

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed for Xubuntu 15.10

My Hardware: Asus EeePC 1201 HA

It has no AMD Graphics Device but the infamous INTEL GMA500 chipset. Because of this I didn't even try to install an ATI video driver. However, the bug be reproduced as follows:

1. Switch to tty1
2. Press [Fn]+[F5] or [Fn]+[F6] to change screen brightness.

My workaround:

```
sudo rmmod eeepc_wmi
```

After this, most Asus Hotkeys will not work, but changing Screen brightness works despite no OSD is showed in graphical environment.

after re-enabling the module,

```
sudo modprobe eeepc_wmi
```

other Asus Hotheys work again but changing screen brightness will freeze the system.

Comment: are you really takling about kernel crashes with kernel 3.18.24? Funny I do not have Fn keys, because its server not notebook.. I guess this answer is totaly off topic :)