# How to install BlackMagic driver for 4.2.0 Linux kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, 15.10

I was trying to install BlackMagic driver on newest Ubuntu 15.10 (64bit) but was stuck with error messages:

```
Setting up desktopvideo (10.5a17) ... Preparing new blackmagic driver
for 4.2.0-16-generic kernel... Adding to DKMS Building (failed)
Preparing new blackmagic-io driver for 4.2.0-16-generic kernel...
Adding to DKMS Building (failed) Loading modules... Enabling systemd
services... DesktopVideoHelper Starting systemd services...
DesktopVideoHelper
********* Failed to build driver(s)

Possible causes:
1. Driver is incompatible with your kernel version
2. Kernel headers/gcc/make/etc. is not installed
3. Kernel header version does not match the running kernel (4.2.0-16-generic)

Error messages: dkms build -m blackmagic -v 10.5a17
---

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area.... make
KERNELRELEASE=4.2.0-16-generic KERNELRELEASE=4.2.0-16-generic.....(bad
exit status: 2) Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel:
4.2.0-16-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.5a17/build/make.log 
for more information.

dkms build -m blackmagic-io -v 10.5a17
---

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area.... make
KERNELRELEASE=4.2.0-16-generic KERNELRELEASE=4.2.0-16-generic....(bad
exit status: 2) ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists:
'/var/crash/desktopvideo.0.crash' Error! Bad return status for module
build on kernel: 4.2.0-16-generic (x86_64) Consult
/var/lib/dkms/blackmagic-io/10.5a17/build/make.log 
for more information.
```

Is there some way to install on newer Linux kernel?

Comment: Is that from "Consult /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic-io/10.5a17/build/make.log for more information." If not see the log and add the relevant parts into the question

Comment: And you probably might be better off posting it here (too): https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewforum.php?f=12&sid=73be363fa0112225d4cd8b3cacb792fb If it is 1. you need them to add support for kernel 4. As far as I can tell they do not yet.

Comment: thanks @Rinzwind for fast feedback, I will try the proposed answer, I registered there but if the patch will work I will just use it and dont ask there.. the log is from dpkg, I think I looked into thtat log and found the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a short procedure for patching the BlackMagic 10.5 drivers to work on 64-bit Debian systems with 4.2.x kernels:

1. Download and unpack the drivers. (Blackmagic_Desktop_Video_Linux_10.5.tar.gz)
2. `sudo apt-get install git` if it isn't there already.
3. `cd Blackmagic_Desktop_Video_Linux_10.5/deb/amd64`
4. Patch the deb using `fakeroot` and [driver code from Github](https://github.com/iperry/blackmagic):

```
    fakeroot sh -c '
      mkdir tmp;
      dpkg-deb -R desktopvideo_10.5a17_amd64.deb tmp;
      cd tmp/usr/src;
      git clone https://github.com/iperry/blackmagic;
      rm -rf blackmagic-10.5a17/ && mv blackmagic blackmagic-10.5a17/;
      git clone https://github.com/iperry/blackmagic-io;
      rm -rf blackmagic-io-10.5a17/ && mv blackmagic-io blackmagic-io-10.5a17/;
      cd ../../../;
      dpkg-deb -b tmp desktopvideo_10.5a17_amd64-patched.deb;
    '
```

5. `sudo dpkg -i desktopvideo_10.5a17_amd64-patched.deb`
6. Continue with the rest of the installation as normal.

Credit [@iperry](https://github.com/iperry) for the driver patch.

Comment: thanks for detailed how-to, I will definitely try it and come back with result

Comment: tested after a long time, works like a charm on Ubuntu 15.10 kernel 4.2.0-16-generic